# MT4 - Place buy and sell limits at certain time

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, forex

I would like to use Meta Trader 4 Expert Advisor to code a trading strategy.

However, I could not find such function in MT4.

A similar function in Python would be datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second).

Essentially I want to do the following:

> Place sell and buy limit when market opens, say UTC +8.

It would be good if someone can help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Daniel's answer, the way I use time is simply using [Hour()](https://docs.mql4.com/dateandtime/hour), [Minute()](https://docs.mql4.com/dateandtime/minute), and [Seconds()](https://docs.mql4.com/dateandtime/seconds).

Note that these return broker server times.

So use case:

```cpp
if(Hour()==14 && Minute()==30 && Seconds()==0){
    int buy = OrderSend(...);
}
```

Comment: Actually I have quite a lot of trouble using MT4 editor. If possible, can you provide a sample code that will allow me to place order at 12am at broker time? Thanks in advance. I know basic syntax in MT4 but quite clueless on which section to place order.

Comment: You can use the above. Change the `14` to `12` and `30` to `00`. And that will allow for execution at `12:00`.

Answer (score 1):

MT4 time is number of seconds past sinse Jan 1, 1970, a special variable type `datetime` is used, which is in fact a simple `int`.
How to constuct time? Two simple ways: from string and from struct.

```
datetime time=StringToTime(StringFormat("%04d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d",year,month,day,hour,minute));
```

Alternatively,

```
MqlDatetime dt;
dt.year=year;
dt.mon=month;
dt.day=day;
dt.hour=hour;
dt.min=minute;
datetime time=StructToTime(dt);
```

What time is available in MT4? Three types of time can be called: 
    current time of the broker (what you actually see on the chart and in the market window) is the default time, you can get it by calling `TimeCurrent()` or `iTime(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,0)`; 
    GMT+0 can be achieved by `TimeGMT()`; and 
    your local PC time can be achieved via `TimeLocal()` function.
Which of them to use - it is up to you.

Placing order by time condition is similar to placing an order with other conditions.

```
if(condition)OrderSend(..);
```